# Error with NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create a predicate from an array of strings like this...

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSCompoundPredicate andPredicateWithSubpredicates:OBJgroup.mARR_predicates];
```

But I am getting an error that would appear to be some kind of memory issue but the strings and array is there and they are valid. The error is...

```
[__NSCFString minimalFormInContext:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc8e4500
```

The error occurs when the fetch request is called like this...

```
NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext]
                           executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

Where is the problem with my predicate?

Answer (score 0):

The array passed into the predicate must be a collection of NSPredicates not strings.